# Процесс загрузки CLR при запуске управляемого модуля

Tags: .net, clr, теория

Каким образом происходит загрузка CLR при запуске управляемого модуля? Насколько я знаю, в Windows XP+ ОС сама распознаёт заголовок CLR, при создании процесса загружает в память MSCorEE.dll и вызывает в ней нужный метод, который организует загрузку CLR. Для запуска в Windows младше XP в IAT содержится запись `mscoree!_CorExeMain`. Как это работает? Запись из себя же ничего не представляет кроме как указания на импортируемую функцию. Её ведь ещё вызвать надо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если взять `.NET` `exe`-файл, и посмотреть в дизассемблере/дебаггере, то можно увидеть, что `EntryPoint` `ехе` модуля содержит простой `JMP` в `mscoree._CorExeMain`. Это не просто импорт, это прямой вызов этой функции.

[image]

Comment: Т.е. точка входа не содержит байт-код?

Comment: Нет, как она может содержать байт-код, если это должен быть валидный нативный exe-файл.

Comment: Интересно ещё вот что: а как CLR создаёт домены? Раз это изолированные разделы, в которых выполняется конкретный исполняемый файл .NET, как они физически выглядят? Не может же CLR разбить память процесса как ей хочется. У процесса есть конкретная структура определяемая ОС.

Comment: Мне известно, что на самом деле изначально создаётся три домена: System, Shared и Default. В Shared загружаются сборки не зависящие от домена. Так вот, что это за сборки? Я должен специально как то указать, что сборку нужно загрузить в SharedDomain или все сборки по-умолчанию туда загружаются? Как происходит взаимодействие с кодом сборок в SharedDomain?

Comment: @D.Stark я не знаю, как это работает, лучше задайте отдельный вопрос